# Как правильно разместить блоки?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Скажите, как сделать так, как в макете? Надпись "Мы хотим сделать этот мир лучше" становится посередине, а нужно как в макете.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
header {
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url(img/header-background.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 232px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.header__logo img {
  float: left;
}

.header__logo p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.header__menu {
  width: 336px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 170px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.header__menu li {
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.header__menu li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.header__menu a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header__title {
  width: 425px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 257px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__logo">
    <img src="img/header-logo.png" alt="header-logo">
    <p>Южный волонтёрский центр</p>
  </div>
  <nav class="header__menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Проекты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Личный кабинет</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="header__title">Мы хотим сделать этот мир лучше</div>
</header>
```

[image: Макет]

[image: То, что выходит у меня]

Answer (score 2):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
header {
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url(img/header-background.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 232px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  position:relative;
}

.header__logo img {
  float: left;
}

.header__logo p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.header__menu {
  width: 336px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 170px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.header__menu li {
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.header__menu li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.header__menu a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header__title {
  width: 425px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 257px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 250px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__logo">
    <img src="img/header-logo.png" alt="header-logo">
    <p>Южный волонтёрский центр</p>
  </div>
  <nav class="header__menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Проекты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Личный кабинет</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="header__title">Мы хотим сделать этот мир лучше</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте

```
text-align: left;
margin-left: 30px;
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью позиционирования, для `header` задать `position:relative;`, а для `header__title: position: absolute;` и с помощью `right` и `bottom` выставить надпись согласно размеров макета, это одно из решений.